# Website is not accessible after force SSL

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I have a big problem with a website I edited for a client. 
My client said he enabled his free SSL from his host. I installed a force https plugin on his wordpress installation. After that, I edited the address to https instead of http (In general settings). 
Now I can't access the website or the wp Login. Apparently the SSL wasn't activated.

This is the error I receive : `ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT`

Is there a way to either change the website address (from the settings) or disable the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

**To disable a plugin:**

Using FTP, go to `wp-content/plugins/`, find the https plugin folder and rename it to something else it.

**For change in general settings:**

You could try to add the following code in *wp-config.php* file:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Another way is to change those values directly in the database. [Here](https://www.hostdime.com/resources/change-wordpress-site-url-via-phpmyadmin/) is one article that shows how to do that.